# int VS uint8_t VS uint16_t

Tags: memory-usage, variables, memory

This question is quite clear. What are the differences between an `int`, an `uint8_t`, and an `uint16_t`. I know it has to do with bytes and memory but can someone clarify me a bit?

Things I want to know:

1- How much memory does each take.

2- When to use what.

3- In the end of the day, are they that different?

Comment: Beware that the compiler does not do arithmetic with anything smaller than `int`. E.g. `(uint8_t) 200 + (uint8_t) 200` does not overflow: the terms are promoted to `int` before the addition and the result is `(int) 400`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can decipher most of them yourself.

- A `u` prefix means `unsigned`.
- The number is the number of bits used. There's 8 bits to the byte.
- The `_t` means it's a `typedef`.

So a `uint8_t` is an unsigned 8 bit value, so it takes 1 byte. A `uint16_t` is an unsigned 16 bit value, so it takes 2 bytes (16/8 = 2)

The only fuzzy one is `int`. That is "a signed integer value at the native size for the compiler". On an 8-bit system like the ATMega chips that is 16 bits, so 2 bytes. On 32-bit systems, like the ARM based Due, it's 32 bits, so 4 bytes.  Of the three it is the only one that changes.

Personally I rarely use `int` and always use `uint8_t` etc., since the variable type is the same no matter what architecture you compile for.  When you use `int` you can run into problems if you had a program that worked fine on a 32-bit ARM but then doesn't work right on an 8-bit ATMega, since the `int` can only store a fraction of the range of numbers on the 8-bit system compared to the 32-bit system.

Comment: Can I make an `uint8_t` array?

Comment: You can make an array of any data type.

Comment: Can I use it like this too: `uint8_t function()`

Comment: Yes. uint8_t is the same as "byte" or "unsigned char".

Comment: If you need negative values, you need to use signed integers. E.g. int16_t.